# What are odds of rolling a 7 three times before rolling a 12 one time? All other rolls do not matter.

Tags: probability, dice

Since other rolls do not matter, I thought I could consider there are only $7$ possible outcomes for each roll, 6 for 7 (1/6, 2/5, 3/4, 4/3, 5/2, 6/1) and 1 for 12 (6/6). So the odds of getting 3 7s before a 12 would simply be $(6/7)^3$ or $62.97\%$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $6/7^3=\frac 6{343} \ll 62.97\%$.  Parentheses, please.  Your logic and your result are correct

Comment: What do you roll?

Comment: You're giving the answer as a probability rather than as odds. The odds in favor of three $7$s before a $12$ are $216 : 127$.